# How to change thumbnail src value in Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js with jQuery to upload files to the server. Afer file uploaded I'm generating a "server-side" filename with the current url.

```
$('.dropzone').dropzone({
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function(file) {
            var newname = generateServersideFilename(file.name); // this is my function
            // here I need a help to find the thumbnail <img> to set the 'src' attribute
        }
    }
});
```

How can I find the current thumbnail `img` to set the `src` attribute?

Comment: Not the best way, but working: `$('span:contains("'+file.name+'")').closest('.dz-preview').find('img').attr('src', newname);` - If you know a better way, please share.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$('.dropzone').dropzone({
    init: function() {
        this.on('success', function(file) {
            var newname = generateServersideFilename(file.name); // this is my function
            // changing src of preview element
            file.previewElement.querySelector("img").src = newname;
        }
    }
});
```

[dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) have few examples of using file.previewElement

Answer (score 4):

This can be simply be

```
this.on("success", function(file) {
var mydropzone = this;
mydropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "images/x.jpg");
});
```

here is the [link](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/How-to-theme-Dropzone) from dropzone

Comment: This should be the correct answer, we should not edit the attribute directly, instead, we should fire a 'thumbnail' event.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.on("addedfile", function (file) {

   file.previewElement.querySelector("img").src = "music-box-outline.svg";

});
```